# Can the server's in-memory cache be used in Azure?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-redis-cache

I need my Web API to have caching to store some data. I have been researching caching on Azure and I can see that Microsoft recommends to use Redis cache.

Can I use the normal server's in-memory cache to store simple data which will only be accessed by the Web API or is Redis my only option.
Are there any limitations of server memory on Azure?

Comment: What Azure Service do you want to use, Azure App Services or Azure Functions or others? What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Azure App Service (Web API) and .NET Core

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, you can. Azure Redis cache is not the only option. You can consider to use [`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2) like `MemoryCache` to store your simple data, and make sure the size of your data is less than the available tails memory size on Azure App Service which be restricted by the memory limit of Azure App Services for different tiers, as the figure below from [`App Service limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits).

[image]
[image]

Meanwhile, even you can consider to implement your Web API by using Azure Functions with HTTP trigger which support more memory, please refer to [`Functions limits`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#functions-limits).

[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks... thats good to know we can keep it simple for simple stuff..

Comment: Let's say, I have about 500 concurrent connections (users using the website) with my MVC5 web app, which is hosted in Azure App Service. I want to use [MemoryCache] and [OutputCache] to store a List with 5000 records and a page with this list of records rendered in an HTML table respectively. Can you please give me a rough idea of how much memory is it going to consume and where can I monitor the usage and all?

Comment: @Junaid I think you can get a rough estimate by looking at how many bytes are in your data. For example if each record contains 2 kilobytes of text then it would be 10 MB total, and if your generated HTML document is 20 MB, then you would have 30 MB in total.